# How to fix these errors in latest build of Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi I'm pretty new to Android programming. I have downloaded the Android eclipse bundle and extracted to a folder and updated the SDK. Later I have created a new 'HelloDroid' program but I am getting these error when the project is created.

Could some one please help me to fix these error and explain why these errors are occurring.

Note: I have installed support upto v.19 starting from Froyo

[image]

Comment: What is you minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml? And Project Build Target in project's Android properties?

Comment: add appcompact lib project in  your project

Comment: @italo: manifesto
android:minSdkVersion="10"
android:targetSdkVersion="19"

Comment: And the "Project Build Target", in project properties?

Comment: import the appcomapct lib project.this project in your sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat

Answer (score 0):

Set compatible values for:

- `minSdkVersion`/`targetSdkVersion` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`
- **Android > Project Build Target** in your project properties
- [Android support libraries](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

After that rebuild the project.